# Codeigniter not redirecting in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, codeigniter-3

I uploaded a codeigniter project to cpanel. But when i click on a link it is not redirecting to the desired controller. Instead is giving error as page not found.
Please help me with this..

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your error or some code?

Comment: Please post the code plus give relevant information like which URL you're visiting.

Comment: i think you forgot to upload .htaccess file!!

Comment: It is working fine in localhost... But not working in cpanel..

Comment: please share your links which you are testing...

Comment: http://stackblender.com/review

Comment: have you set your default_controller ?

Comment: Is the review folder root of your application?

Comment: Yes i have set my default controller..

Comment: please share your default controller name ?

Comment: auth.. I have all the code enclosed in that only..

Comment: do you have index as an action in your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below steps and everything will work in codeigniter:

https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/

Also please do not forgot to add .htaccess file at root.

Comment: I have done all the changes in the config file as  $config['index_page'] = "" and also i have changed  $route["default_controller"]= "My_Controller"

Comment: Could you please share your URL?

Comment: I have done all the changes in the config file as $config['index_page'] = "" and also i have changed $route["default_controller"]= "My_Controller

Comment: name of your folder is review?

Comment: So did you add that name in .htaccess file rewrite base Your_website_folder/

Comment: The name of your default controller?

Comment: auth... I used ion_auth library